# Qt Loading message should stay on top of and centered to parent widget

Tags: c++, qt

How to create a QWidget (QDialog?) that stays on top of the parent Widgt but not other Applications like Qt::WindowsStaysOnTopHint? I want to show a little "loading" message.

EDIT: for clarification

The message should stay in centered place of the widget when moving the main window around.
Do I need to connect the move signals from the main window to manually keep the widget in the right place?

I don't want to block the whole application itself (no dialog.exec()), I just want to say the user should wait and prevent user input (maybe not to all widgets, but parent widget)

Comment: So you want other windows(of your program) not to accept inputs?

Comment: And have you tried QProgressDialog?

Comment: @saeed Yes, but I don't want to block the whole application itself (no exec()), just want to say the user should wait and prevent user input (maybe not to all widgets, but parent widget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I don't used setModal and something like that. Just show() and hide() the dialog and it should stay on top of it's parent. I added push and pop (like a stack) because different threads might be interested in showing/hiding the dialog... so it should be guaranteed that only the last call hides the dialog. Other solutions are welcome... this is just quick and dirty.

```
class WaitDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        WaitDialog(const QString& message, QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void show();
    void hide();
    void push();
    void pop();

signals:
        void visibilityChanged(bool enable);

private:
    int stack;
        QLabel* msgLabel;
};

WaitDialog::WaitDialog(const QString &message, QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),
      msgLabel(new QLabel(message, this)),
      stack(0)
{
    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->setContentsMargins(30, 30, 30, 30);
    mainLayout->addWidget(msgLabel);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
}

void WaitDialog::show()
{
    QDialog::show();

        emit visibilityChanged(true);
}

void WaitDialog::hide()
{
    QDialog::hide();
    emit visibilityChanged(false);
}

void WaitDialog::push()
{
    stack++;
    show();

    emit visibilityChanged(true);
}

void WaitDialog::pop()
{
    if (stack > 0)
        --stack;
    if (stack == 0)
    {
        hide();
    }
}
```

So anything I do is just

```
connect(someObject, SIGNAL(someProcessingFinished()), waitDialog, SLOT(pop()));
```

to automatically hide the dialog and manually call waitDialog->push() when start processing (or wire it against some someProcessingStarted() method).

The dialog itself is instantiated this way:

WaitDialog* waitDialog = new WaitDialog(tr("Loading data... please wait."), this);

and got its parent in the second param (this in the example).

Works for me to let the main window pop up a message that stays as long as required to stop ui interaction but keeping the application running instead of waiting for the dialog to return. Not used modality flags etc. I just connected interested widgets to the visibilityChanged() signal emitted by the WaitDialog.

```
connect(waitDialog, SIGNAL(visibilityChanged(bool)), someControl, SLOT(doSomething(bool)));
```

... and for example the following code do disable/enable the control whenever the WaitDialog changes visibility...

```
void SomeControl::doSomething(bool enabled)
{
    setEnabled(!enabled);
}
```

[Look my question and answer here to get know how to keep it centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385916/how-to-keep-a-qwidget-or-qdialog-centered-to-its-parent-widget).

Answer (score 2):

If you read documentation of `QDialog::setModal()` carefully then you should find proper solution. 
Just Use QDialog with paret set to your window and set its [windowModality](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) to [Qt::WindowModal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#WindowModality-enum).

Docs says:

> Qt::WindowModal - The window is modal to a single window hierarchy and
>   blocks input to its parent window, all grandparent windows, and all
>   siblings of its parent and grandparent windows.

Comment: setmodal() will block the whole ui access, not only the parent

Comment: I've wrote about reading documentation of QDialog::setModal and catch related things not using it! Solution is simple: setParent, setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal), show().