# How to keep a QWidget (or QDialog) centered to its parent widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to keep a QWidget (or QDialog) centered to its parent widget. Is it really required to connect to signals of the parent widget or is there an easier way (something to set)?

Comment: what have you tried? what would the signals have to do with keeping a widget centered?

Comment: tried overriding QWidget::moveEvent but this forces me to change the parent widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it myself and just to answer my own question if someone will find it helpful.

Keep it in the center:

```
void MyMainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event)
{
    const QPoint global = this->mapToGlobal(rect().center());
    waitDialog->move(global.x() - waitDialog->width() / 2, global.y() - waitDialog->height() / 2);
}
```

... where `waitDialog` is an instance of my "Wait..." indicator. This needs to override the `moveEvent` method of the parent (here `MyMainWindow`).

Answer (score 0):

If your QWidget is an in-the-same-window child of its parent, then you could add it to the parent's QLayout (e.g. QBoxLayout or QGridLayout) with the proper settings to have the layout center it.

If it's a QDialog (or some other QWidget that is set to be its own separately-moveable top-level window), then the QLayout approach won't work; what you could do instead is override the parent widget's resizeEvent() method to call setGeometry() on the child dialog, so that the child dialog gets its position and/or size updated whenever the parent gets resized.  You might also need to override the moveEvent() method of the parent's top-level-window to detect when the user has moved the parent window, so that you can move the dialog's position to match that movement.  I'm not 100% sure this is behavior you would really want though, since normally the user expects to be able to move dialogs about the screen independently of their parent windows.

Comment: parent is a main window or tabwidget and the widget to keep centered is a qdialog/qwidget that can't be added to the layout of the parent (resize does not solve the problem with moving the window around using the titlebar, or not?)

Comment: It's not clear whether "the problem with moving the window around using the titlebar" refers to the user dragging on the title bar of the parent window, or the title bar of the child dialog.  If it's the former, overriding the parent window's moveEvent() should work.  If it's the latter, you might just want to get rid of the dialog's title bar entirely, e.g. by calling setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup) or setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint) on it before showing it.

Comment: it is the title bar of the parent window