# How to center a QDialog in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

I have this example code:

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(this);
QPoint dialogPos = dialog->mapToGlobal(dialog->pos());
QPoint thisPos = mapToGlobal(this->pos());
dialog->exec();
```

But the Dialog is not centered on his parent. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I'm calling Dialog from constructor in MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    this->panelInferior = new WidgetTabsInferior;
    this->acciones = new Acciones(this);

    crearAcciones();
    crearBarraMenu();
    crearToolbar();
    crearTabsEditor();
    crearArbolDir();
    crearDockWindows();
    crearStatusBar();

    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":imgs/logo.png"));

    connect(this->pestanasEditor , SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)),this,SLOT(cambioTab(int)));

    this->dialogo = new AcercaDe(this);
    this->dialogo->move(x() + (width() - dialogo->width()) / 2,
                 y() + (height() - dialogo->height()) / 2);
    this->dialogo->show();
    this->dialogo->raise();
    this->dialogo->activateWindow();

}
```

But I get is:

[image]

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43802-Centering-child-window-in-parent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385916/how-to-keep-a-qwidget-or-qdialog-centered-to-its-parent-widget

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep a QWidget (or QDialog) centered to its parent widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385916/how-to-keep-a-qwidget-or-qdialog-centered-to-its-parent-widget)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have this code in [github](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt/blob/master/lqUty/CenterWidgets.h)

```
inline void CenterWidgets(QWidget *widget, QWidget *host = 0) {
    if (!host)
        host = widget->parentWidget();

    if (host) {
        auto hostRect = host->geometry();
        widget->move(hostRect.center() - widget->rect().center());
    }
    else {
        QRect screenGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
        int x = (screenGeometry.width() - widget->width()) / 2;
        int y = (screenGeometry.height() - widget->height()) / 2;
        widget->move(x, y);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

*edit*

fix the deprecation warning issued from recent Qt versions:

```cpp
#include <QScreen>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGuiApplication>

inline void CenterWidgets(QWidget *widget, QWidget *host = Q_NULLPTR) {
    if (!host)
        host = widget->parentWidget();

    if (host) {
        auto hostRect = host->geometry();
        widget->move(hostRect.center() - widget->rect().center());
    }
    else {
        QRect screenGeometry = QGuiApplication::screens()[0]->geometry();
        int x = (screenGeometry.width() - widget->width()) / 2;
        int y = (screenGeometry.height() - widget->height()) / 2;
        widget->move(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works only on the first screen. If you're trying to center on a different screen, you have to add screenGeometry.x() and screenGeometry.y() to x and y.

Comment: @goug What do you mean? Show example? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Thought I would post my own solution here. @CapelliC's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42326134/4628115) works, but is deprecated since Qt5.11. Infact, the documentation says the [QDesktopWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) class is obsolete.

**Solution** (*which is a litte crude*) is to use the [QGuiApplication::screenAt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screenAt)

*Context:* class inheriting [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html), but can can extend for any [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html)

```
// Get current screen size
QRect rec = QGuiApplication::screenAt(this->pos())->geometry();

// Using minimum size of window
QSize size = this->minimumSize();

// Set top left point
QPoint topLeft = QPoint((rec.width() / 2) - (size.width() / 2), (rec.height() / 2) - (size.height() / 2));

// set window position
setGeometry(QRect(topLeft, size));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the geometry of the QDialog:

```
dialog->move(x() + (width() - dialog->width()) / 2,
             y() + (height() - dialog->height()) / 2);
```

The [`move()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qwidget.html#move-1) function moves respect the parent, so it is not necessary to map to global.

On constructor the position and size of parent are not set yet. You can try executing the dialog in a separate method or, if needed on constructor, try with something like

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, [=]() {
  // ... your dialog code
});
```

It will be shown on the next iteration of the event loop.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question, the dialog not works correctly. :(

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a Qt4 bug. I used Qt4 on Ubuntu and it doesn't respect the parent widget center.

However, when I use Qt5, It seems to work fine.

You can also use `move()` to arrive to your position.